# CSS: Suppressing negative margins of child elements

Tags: javascript, css

I have a parent element (e.g. a div) which surrounds some dynamic content. I would like the parent div to fully contain the child elements in as many circumstances as possible.

One problem is child elements with negative margin settings, which cause the child element to be displayed outside of the parent element (and also cause the parent element not to be of the desired size).

So

1. Is there any css trick that can be applied to the parent in order to suppress the negative margins in the child elements (e.g. without having to modify the styles on the child).
2. Failing that, is there anyway to detect via javascript whether a particular element has overflowing content? (and in which direction and to what degree the content is overflowing?)

Comment: you can use a positive padding on parent element to move the child back, it would change height and width tho.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to put a class to the parent like:

```
.parentDiv > * {
  margin:0 !important;
}
```

To have the parent with the desired height, you need to set some css too:

```
.parentDiv{
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    background:#DFE;
    padding:5px;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't tried that - I'll give it a go and get back to you.

Comment: One problem though, is that I don't really want to affect positive margins on child elements.  But I'll see if I can do something with this.

Answer (score 1):

There is a javascript method of handling this, but it's certainly not as clean as @Mic's CSS solution. I haven't completely tested this, and you may need to add some support for various padding/margin adjustments, but it would get somebody started if a JS-solution was the only option. Using prototype.js (jquery would be similar, but plain javascript will be very.. stretchy):

```
function checkOverflow (child) {
  child = $(child);
  if (child.descendants().any()) {
    child.getElementsBySelector("> *").each(function(e) {
      checkOverflow(e);
    });
  }

  var parent = child.up();

  var child_left = child.cumulativeOffset()['left'], child_top = child.cumulativeOffset()['top'];
  var child_height = child.getDimensions()['height'], child_width = child.getDimensions()['width'];

  var parent_left = parent.cumulativeOffset()['left'], parent_top = parent.cumulativeOffset()['top'];
  var parent_height = parent.getDimensions()['height'], parent_width = parent.getDimensions()['width'];

  if (child_top < parent_top) {
    if (child_left < parent_left) {
      // adjust element style here
    } else if (child_left > parent_left + parent_width) {
      // adjust element style here
    }
  } else if (child_top > parent_top + parent_height) {
    if (child_left < parent_left) {
      // adjust element style here
    } else if (child_left > parent_left + parent_width) {
      // adjust element style here
    }
  }
}
```

My general feeling, though, is that you should only do this if it can't be explicitly done through CSS.

Comment: Thanks Adam - Interesting approach.  I would rather use css, but I have a feeling I wont be able to accomplish it with css alone, so something along these lines may be necessary.

Comment: Oh, and a quick note, this is using prototype.js.